# Why the variable J is always 0? For inside a For - Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

IntelliJ says "j++" is never used and I just can't figure out why.

What I'm trying to do is check if exists 2 accounts of the type Conta searching by the their attribute "numero" with getNumero. And I just search for the second account if the first one exists.

PS: listaClientes is an ArrayList of the type Conta

```
for(int i = 0; i < listaClientes.size(); i++){
                if(listaClientes.get(i).getNumero() == numContaOrigem){
                    System.out.println("Qual o numero da conta de destino? (TRANSFERÊNCIA)");
                    int numContaDestino = teclado.nextInt();
                    // -------- Here is the problem --------- vvvv --------------
                    for (int j = 0; j < listaClientes.size(); j++){
                        if(listaClientes.get(j).getNumero() == numContaDestino){
                            System.out.println("Qual o valor da transferencia?");
                            double valorTransf = teclado.nextDouble();
                            if(listaClientes.get(i).transferencia(valorTransf, listaClientes.get(j))){
                                System.out.println("Transferência realizada!");
                                return;
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("Saldo insuficiente! Transferência não realizada!");
                                return;
                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Cliente destino não encontrado!");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Cliente origem não encontrado!");
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < listaClientes.size(); j++){
  if(listaClientes.get(j).getNumero() == numContaDestino){
    ...
  }else{
    System.out.println("Cliente destino não encontrado!");
    return; /* ! this return is why j++ is not used ! */
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize the else condition would be true multiple times.